# CruiseControl.net - Is there a way to run a batch file that will copy (msi) files to another server in a different domain?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, ccnet-config

I have an issue where I am trying to copy files(msi) from our build server to our Test server in CruiseControl.  Once these are copied over we are planning on having a Scheduled Task that will run silent installs nightly.  I need to be able to push back to CruiseControl the status of that build.

I am having issues copying these files from a batch file that is being run in our cruisecontrol prooject.  I'm pretty sure its a permissions issue.

Also is there a way to push the build status back to CruiseControl so that it could tell us when the install failed?

Answer (score 0):

Not a simple solution available, I'm afraid. Only time I saw anything similar done was using a python script to invoke commands on a remote system using ssh.